# Is *.localhost resolving to 127.0.0.1 standardized?

Tags: domain-name-system

I noticed that pinging `whatever.localhost` resolves to `127.0.0.1`. I'm on macos.

Is that a standard behavior (resolving `*.localhost` to `127.0.0.1`) I can rely on? Does it work on Linux or Windows the same way?

Comment: At least on Debian Linux it does not automatically resolve to 127.0.0.1, but I think adding the subdomains to `/etc/hosts` doesn't violate any standard. You only cannot assume it resolves on any system without explicitely adding it to the resolver (e.g. hosts or a local DNS server)

Comment: I've had some quirky behaviour where it resolved to `::1` but the app wasn't expecting IPv6 traffic.

Comment: Related to a question I asked here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88636/why-does-chrome-resolve-websitename-localhost-as-localhost. At the time I noticed that Chrome was doing the translation and other browsers didn't resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1. One of the answers to my question brought up this proposal: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-let-localhost-be-localhost-06

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should on most systems. The [RFC itself](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6761#section-6.3) says name resolution SHOULD return the loopback address for anything inside .localhost.

> The domain "localhost." and any names falling within **".localhost."**
> are special in the following ways:

(skip a bit)

> Name resolution APIs and libraries SHOULD recognize localhost
> names as special and **SHOULD always return the IP loopback address
> for address queries**

SHOULD is not quite the same as MUST, but I'd expect almost all systems to follow that behaviour. I can't think of any linux or windows systems I've used that don't.

Comment: I use `*.localhost` for web development and I have never had an operating system cause an issue. I have had issues with Chrome not recognizing an SSL certificate for `*.localhost`, so I have moved to `*.dev.localhost` which also works fine.

Comment: I can't think of many systems that _do_ follow this behavior. Especially on older Linux systems, where the `localhost` lookup was done through a static entry in /etc/hosts (which had no concept of wildcard or suffix matching). Was your "should" based on testing or purely based on what the RFC says?

Comment: @user1686 I'm using SHOULD in the way [RFC2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119) describes it.

Answer (score -1):

The literal answer is no. It is standartized (as discussed in the other answer) to be the loopback address which can be 127.0.0.1, ::1 or both. Besides it a SHOULD, so some might not have set it up like that. Besides a user can override localhost to whatever else on many systems.

At least on Windows it is the case lately that localhost rezolves to both ::1 and 127.0.0.1 with ::1 taking precedence. Sometimes it actually leads to issues when user launches a service that only listens on IPv4 and other tools are unable to reach it via localhost as that name prods ::1.